# How to receive H.264 stream and decoding in UWP app?

Tags: c#, video-streaming, h.264, windows-10-universal

I want to write a windows 10 application which receives custom H.264 stream from the Internet and then decode and render the picture,but I don't know how to start, are there any demo or link about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean custom H.264 stream? UWP app supports H.264 video and for adaptive streaming, UWP supports HLS and DASH. You may try use one of them.

Comment: Which I get from internet are packets which contains H.264 NALU. How can I decode and render it?

Comment: [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ad2299b6-3961-4e66-9cf9-05df8e38cdc6/uwp-how-to-use-hardware-accelerated-h264-decoding-in-uwp-app?forum=wpdevelop) on MSDN might be helpful.